# Can anyone explain the concatenation on #define like that:

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#define CONC_BIT(b7,b6,b5,b4,b3,b2,b1,b0) Conc_help(b7,b6,b5,b4,b3,b2,b1,b0)
#define Conc_help(b7,b6,b5,b4,b3,b2,b1,b0) 0b##b7##b6##b5##b4##b3##b2##b1##b0
```

The goal of this code "in embedded system" to concatenate all 8 pins in one                   called port in "Digital Input Output"

Comment: lookup token pasting

Comment: I have a proper answer that's better than the suggested dupe... But I didn't finish typing it before the question was closed ‍♂️

Comment: I still did not understand from the duplicated answer ... What's the benefit of adding a "Conc_help" why not add ( 0b##b7##b6##b5##b4##b3##b2##b1##b0)  along